# Could not execute a Bash Script if / while

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I would like if someone points out mistakes in my script. The source where I'm learning from is so buggy that's why it's confusing me.

**PURPOSE OF THIS SCRIPT:** It will count the numbers from whatever number the user enters to number 1

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n Enter a number

read number

if (($number > 0))  ; then

index = $number

while [ $index => 1 ]  ; do

echo $index

((index--))



break
done
fi
```

**ERROR IT GIVES:** index: command not found

Comment: which source are you using? you can use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to catch typos/syntax error/etc and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is a good source for learning bash scripting

Comment: indenting your code is a good way to make your script more readable, and especially to get a visual overview of the structure of the code.  Indent by two or four spaces or a tab each time your code enters a new control structure (like `if` or a `case` statement, or after the `do` in a `while` or `for`) and un-indent by the same amount whenever that ends  (e.g. `fi` or `esac` or `done`).   You can also split long lines with a \ at the end of line (not needed if the line ends with a `|` pipe character) - indent continued lines too.  whitespace is free, use it to make your code readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `index = $number` cannot use spaces around `=` for variable assignment.. use `index=$number` or `((index = number))`
- `[ $index => 1 ]` I suppose you want to check if `index` is greater than or equal to 1, use `[ $index -ge 1 ]` or `((index >= 1))`
- why is the `break` statement used? it is used to quit loop
- also the `if` statement is not required
- you can also use `read -p` option to add message for user

putting it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter a number: ' number

while ((number >= 1)) ; do
    echo $number
    ((number--))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you might want to take a look at

```
man index
```

A corrected version of your script works if you replace the variable name

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n Enter a number

read num

   if (($num > 0))  ; then

      ind=$num

      while [ $ind -ge 1 ]  ; do

         echo $ind

         ((ind--))

         break
         done
   fi
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code? It makes it easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the "if" before

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

I guess you want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a number : "
read number
echo $number

if [ $number -gt "0" ]  ; then
  ind="$number"
  while [ $ind -ge "1" ]  ; do
     echo $ind   
    ((ind--))
  done
fi
```